# Calling Google Cloud Buckets from Google Cloud internal IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-networking

I have a bucket (`my-bucket-name`) with a file (`my-large-file.zip`) on Google Cloud. I created a signed URL, with `GET` permission, to download the file.

My download URL looks like this:

> https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket-name/my-large-file.zip?GoogleAccessId=...

When I downloading this URL from my developer PC (outside Google Cloud), it's working by downloading the file *via the internet*.

My Google Cloud deployed applications using the same URLs and downloads them. I'm wondering if the file is transferred also via the internet? Or maybe I can download the file via the *internal network*. I expecting that the download performance will be much faster.

Is this possible to download the file without using the internet when the code is running on Google Cloud?

Comment: This is not guaranteed. If you are using the Premium network, then all requests stay within Google's backbone when possible. However, don't expect big changes in network speed. Performance depends on many factors, CPU speed, distance, number of hops, etc. You will just have to implement and test. Your question needs exact details on the source service, regions, etc.

Answer (score 3):

**Is this possible to download the file without using the internet when the code is running on Google Cloud?**

If you run your code on a VM instances with only internal (private) IP addresses,
you can enable : [Private Google Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options)

> VM instances that only have internal IP addresses (no external IP
> addresses) can use Private Google Access. They can reach the external
> IP addresses of Google APIs and services
>
> [Note](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access): Even though the IP addresses for Google APIs and services are
> public, the traffic path from instances that are using Private Google
> Access to the Google APIs remains within Google's network

[image]

> Note: Even though the next hop for the required routes is called
> "default internet gateway" and the IP addresses for Google APIs and
> services are public, requests to Google APIs and services from VMs
> that have only internal IP addresses in subnet-a (where Private Google
> Access is enabled) are not sent through the public internet. Those
> requests stay within Google's network. Additionally, VMs that only
> have internal IP addresses do not meet the internet access
> requirements for access to other public IP addresses beyond those for
> Google APIs and services.

## EDIT

I created a Google VM instance with only internal IP address on my default subnet with private access on. I was not able to reach the internet from my VM but I could access cloud Google Cloud Storage with `gsutil`, and also was able to download a blob with `wget`. From my understanding, from the documentation and from my tests the trafic path from my instance to Google APis remains within Google's network.

Comment: Interesting! So, I using Kubernetes cluster. I checked the pods' sub-network and found that `Private Google access=ON`. So, if I understand you right - I have to keep using the *same* URL (like the I'm using in my developer machine) but it will be routed inside Google network WITHOUT reaching the internet?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some form of interconnect between your on-premises and Google cloud, you/your network admins would want to enable this version of Google Cloud private access:  https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options#pga-onprem if you wish to avoid your developer PC accessing Google Cloud Storage via the Internet.

Whether that will result in higher-throughput downloads will depend on many particulars, including *but likely not limited to*:

- round-trip-time, either via the Internet or the interconnect
- configuration of maximum TCP window size advertised by your on-premises PC.

For bulk transfers, one common limit to TCP throughput is:

Throughput <= WindowSize / RoundTripTime